# I need specific data from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 8500 users in my database in firebase.
I tried to get the emails from all the users
but I got all the data and it takes too much time
Is there a way to just get only this data?
my model is

```
   {
    users:{
        userId:{
            name: true,
            adress:{
                street: someStreet,
                city: someCity
            },
            email:someEmail
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to structure your data to support the queries you want to perform.  This may mean duplicating data so that each query only fetches the data it requires.

Comment: When say you *get all the data*, what does that mean? How are you getting all of the data? Do you have some example code? Also, what does *takes too much time* mean? With my Swift app, I can load 10,000 emails in .9 seconds from a structure similar to yours. Can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2):

To get the email, try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
  String email=datas.child("email").getValue().toString();
    }
}

 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

   }
});
```

Since you want the email of all users then you need to loop inside the `userId` to get those email.

Usually the User node is like this:

```
Users
  userid
     email: emailhere
     name: namehere
     key: value
```

So to get emails of all users you can loop inside the userid to get them. If you did not use `userid` and used random id generated by `push()` you will have to loop also to get all the emails.

Another alternative is to create an `email` node that will only contain emails of the users:

```
Email
  user1Email: email_here
  user2Email: email_here
  user3Email: email_here
```

Comment: The OP said he *gets all the data* which is part of the issue. Doesn't this solution get all of the data and therefore would have the same issue?

Comment: First I explained to the OP, the way to be able to retrieve the `email`, we dont know how he is retrieving because he did not provide any code. Second, no if you check the alternative way that is the solution that he wants, he will only get the emails in that way..

Comment: I got that - my question is that the OP is already getting ALL of his data (not a query) and if you look, it's not really that much data - a couple hundred bytes per node. What kind of significant improvement would it be to read 50 bytes vs a couple hundred? (.5Mb vs 1.0Mb) Keep in mind, we're talking less bytes per node; an email address vs an email address, city, name and street; that will literally be a fraction of a second difference. I tested it here and it's .02379s difference with 8500 nodes -  try it yourself!

Comment: I know it does not take time, and it should not or this would be a very bad design by the developers. But, I'm just giving OP an alternative because he asked that if he used the alternative solution it will barely affect I know that, but that is what he asked for anyway..

Comment: But also I think the internet connection will affect in retrieving the data, when he uses the for loop he will be iterating in every `userid` to be able to get the email, and with slow internet connection this will take alot of time. That is why just having the emails only in a list would help him also